# want to bulk replace "1/1" with "1/2" using sed

Tags: sed, replace

I want to replace "1/1" with "1/2" in all files in a directory

I tried

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/1/1/1/2/g' {} +
```

and got

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
```

what am i doing wrong?
how to use this when i need replace it with pattern containing "/"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Comment: Either `sed -e 's/1\/1/1\/2/g'` (quote the slash) or `sed -e 's@1/1@1/2@g'` (use a different separator), whichever method you like better.

Answer (score 0):

The substitute(`s`) command have forward slashes that delimits it. Its format is :

```
s/pattern/replacement/flag
```

The real question here is how you would tackle the forward slashes which appear in your pattern. You can escape the forward slashes in your pattern
which is the ***dirty*** way to do it.

Fortunately `sed` allows different delims for `s` command So you could do something like

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's#1/1#1/2#g' {} \;
```

Here note the use of `#` as the delim for `s` which helps you avoid an influx of backslashes in your substitution.

Comment: Thanks. will work and post the update.